# Proper pronunciation of "Aho-Corasick?"

Tags: terminology

Tomorrow I'm going to be teaching a class on Aho-Corasick string matching. I'm pretty sure I know how to pronounce Margaret Corasick's name, but I don't actually know the proper pronunciation of Alfred Aho's surname.

Can anyone comment on the proper pronunciation so that I can properly give credit where credit is due?

Thanks!

Comment: I always thought it was "Ah-ho" with a broad *a*, but in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfoSbffSIQ4) the MC pronounces it "Ay-ho" with a long *a* as in *gator*.